# print dataframe row values and column headers as a string

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to both python and pandas so please forgive me as I believe this should be easy. So if I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    col1 col2 col3
0    13   23   93
1    11   99   15
2    88   25   55
```

and a user specifies they want row 1. How do I print a string like this:

col1 - 11, col2 - 99, col3 - 15

I know I can get at the row by using df.iloc[[1]] but from there I get lost. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
", ".join(["{} - {}".format(k, v) for k, v in df.iloc[1].to_dict().items()])
```

1. [`.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) generates the dictionary `{'col1': 11, 'col2': 99, 'col3': 15}` from the row.
2. the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) generates a list of "col_name - value" strings
3. the strings in the list are [joined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) together, glued by ", "

Final result:

```
col1 - 11, col2 - 99, col3 - 15
```